# JQuery UI dialog modal disabled option not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I seem to have a strange issue and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this or can see where I'm going wrong.

I have a jquery ui dialog modal and when I initialise it I set the disabled flag to true as I don't want it showing until it gets called by the user.
this is the code I use:

```
function wkgp_config_modal(aWorkgroup, isDisabled){
    $("#wkgp_config_modal").dialog({disabled: isDisabled,
            height: 100,
            modal: true,
            title: aWorkgroup+" config setup",
            resizable:false,
            overlay:{opacity:0,
                     background:"white"}
    });
}
```

This function gets called from my init.js file here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  wkgp_config_modal("test", false);
  //other code here not related to issue
}
```

The function gets called and all the other settings like resizable are correct, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong, Any advice would be great cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what the `disabled` option is really supposed to do. I think it keeps your dialog from doing anything when you attempt to call its methods.

To avoid opening the dialog immediately upon creation, however, you set the `autoOpen` option to `false`.

```
var wkgp_config_modal = function (aWorkgroup, autoOpen) {
    //default autoOpen to true
    autoOpen = (typeof autoOpen !== 'boolean' || autoOpen);

    //alternatively, default autoOpen to false
    //autoOpen = (typeof autoOpen === 'boolean' && autoOpen);

    $('#wkgp_config_modal').dialog({
            autoOpen: autoOpen,
            height: 100,
            modal: true,
            title: aWorkgroup + ' config setup',
            resizable:false,
            overlay:{
                opacity:0,
                background:"white"
            }
    });
};
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick cheers, I was under the impression from the docs that disabled was the way to go, oh well live and learn.